# What does `This command requires a keg argument` mean?

Tags: homebrew

I want to brew rm mtr and its deps, so I execute

```
brew rm mtr
brew rm $(join <(brew leaves) <(brew deps mtr))
```

But it says `This command requires a keg argument`. What is the keg argument?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that command is doing what you think it is.

Those < redirects aren't doing what you think and so the brew command getting executed is

```
brew rm
```

This requires an argument.

I like your attempt at using join without a temp file. After a glance at the man page, I'm pretty sure you cannot do that.

Try this:

```
brew leaves > leaves
brew rm $(brew deps mtr | join leaves -)
```

Comment: does brew deps mtr | join leaves - return any results? Sounds like there are no mtr leaves.